# Is the electric force a vector or a vector field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, vector-fields, coulombs-law

The electric force (Coulomb's law) on a point charge $Q_2$ due to $Q_2$:
\begin{gather*}
\mathbf{F}_{12}=\frac{Q_1Q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1}{|\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1|^3}
\end{gather*}

The seperation vector between the charges is $\mathbf{r}_{12}=\mathbf{r}_2-\mathbf{r}_1=(x_2-x_1)\hat{\textbf{i}}+(y_2-y_1)\hat{\textbf{j}}=(z_2-z_1)\hat{\textbf{k}}
$.

Does this mean that the force is a vector field or just a vector?

Is the force a function of $\mathbf{r}_{12}$, so $\mathbf{F}_{12}=\mathbf{F}_{12}(\mathbf{r}_{12})$?

Answer (score 1):

The electric force is just a vector, not a vector field.

The Coulomb force formula you wrote depends on "some" position vectors $\vec r_1,\vec r_2$, much like fields $\Phi(\vec r)$ depend on the position vector $\vec r$, but it's a different kind of a dependence.

First, a field must depend on a single position in space, $\vec r$, while the Coulomb force depends on two.

Second, different values of the vector $\vec r$ that a field $\Phi(\vec r)$ depends upon must be equally "true" and equally "exist" at the same moment. So both $\Phi(\vec r_\textrm{Boston},t)$ and $\Phi(\vec r_\textrm{Paris},t)$ exist at a given moment $t$. On the other hand, the Coulomb force is a force between two particular objects that sit at particular places $\vec r_1,\vec r_2$, so one choice of values of $\vec r_1,\vec r_2$ is "right" while all others are "wrong". The electric force you mention only depends on $t$ because the locations $\vec r_1,\vec r_2$ of the two charged objects are functions of $t$ themselves.

So the dependence of the force is $\vec F(\vec r_1(t),\vec r_2(t))$. Because time $t$ is the only independent variable, there are no independent spatial variables and we don't talk about a field.

Above, I assumed that we talk about "particular" charged objects. That was justified because you wrote "particular" charges $Q_1,Q_2$ which indicate that we talk about well-defined objects. If you omitted $Q_2$, you would get a formula for the electric field $\vec E(\vec r_2)$ which *is* a field. It's the electric force (from the $Q_1$ at $\vec r_1$ source) per unit charge that you would get *if* you placed the charge at the point $\vec r_2$.

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand. If we fix one of the two particles $j$ than the force only depends on the other $\textbf{r}_i$; if we choose to fix neither, than the displacement $\textbf{r}$ can be chosen at hand as variable, can it not? Dividing by $Q_2$ we certainly get a field, but that would conceptually be equivalent to fix charge and position of one of the two on the right hand side of the force and only consider the remaining as variable, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Dear Gennaro, whether something is a field isn't given just by its "dependence" on some variables, as I argued, so you are just repeating the same misc0nception and completely ignoring everything I wrote. A field is something that objectively exists at each point of space. The transition from mechanics to field theory was a transition in physics in which the number of dynamical variables increased from a "few" at each moment, $\vec x(t)$, to "infinitely many" at each moment, $\Phi(\vec r,t)$. There's some information at each point of space.

Comment: Now, the force $\vec F$ is a concept from mechanics, by $\vec F = m \vec a$, it determines acceleration of objects. It is *not* a concept that requires field theory, so it's always wrong to say that a particular force is a "field". Saying that a force is a "field" is exactly as wrong as saying that the position of the Earth $\vec r_{\rm Earth}$ is a field. It also depends on some position vector - it's equal to that vector - but that's not enough for something to be a "field". A field is a collection of infinitely many variables that may have independent values from each other at a moment $t$.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused due to the wikipedia article of Coulomb's law. I can't grasp the difference between this two form of the force:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Vector_form
Link two: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#System_of_discrete_charges

In "vector form" the force is not at function om $\mathbf{r}$, so it's not a vector field, just a vector?

But in the second link it's just a vector addition of the forces but now the force is a function of $\mathbf{r}$, so it is a vector field?

Comment: @JDoeDoe - the two expressions for the force are clearly exactly the same. $\vec r_{21}$ is just a shortcut for $\vec r_1-\vec r_2$. So replacing one by the other obviously cannot influence any important statement about physics, e.g. the question whether something is a field or how many fields are there. The Wikipedia page surely doesn't say that the force itself is a field. That's something you seem to be adding and the reasons why you do so are completely irrational. Why don't you start reading a definition of fields if you want to use the word? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)

Comment: A field is something that assigns a value or values to each point in space and time. So it has to be a collection of more or less independent numbers $\Phi(x,y,z,t)$ - so that the value of $\Phi$ for one value of $x,y,z,t$ may be chosen independently from the values of the fields at all other points. That's clearly not satisfied by the force between two particular charges.

Comment: A field is something you may potentially see (or imagine), something filling space that has some "shape", like the pictures  http://www.fyzikalni-experimenty.cz/cz/foto-E116_S002-F.JPEG - the shape objectively exists and different kinds of the picture could be changed pretty much independently from others. Your and Gennaro's idea that whenever you see some dependence on a variable called $\vec r$, it's a field, is just wrong - naively "reversely" heuristically extracted from some examples, but otherwise unusable in most other situations in physics.

Comment: I see, but pardon me, I still don't understand what *"objectively exists at each point of space"* means. *"A field is something that assigns a value or values to each point in space and time"* I agree and still don't see the difference with $\textbf{F}(x(t), y(t), z(t), t)$: how is that not satisfied by the force between to particular charges, the mutual distance beeing the variable we look at?

Comment: I don't see a way to meaningfully communicate with someone who "doesn't understand what it means for a field value to objectively exist at each point". The difference between $\vec E(x,y,z,t)$ and $\vec F(x(t),y(t),z(t),t)$ is that the latter is a function of one variable $t$, and is therefore not a field, while the former is a function of 4 spacetime variables, and is a field.

Comment: @LubošMotl Well, you could try using standard terminology, for example; I have never encountered the word *objectively* in physics. Moreover *"the latter is a function of one variable $t$, and is therefore not a field, while the former is a function of 4 spacetime variables, and is a field"*: would this imply that only functions depending on more than one variable can be considered fields? Either you want to express that we want $x$ not to depend on $t$ but be independent by itself (I agree, but you're using way overterminology for it) or I still don't see it.

Comment: Yes, "fields" are only used for variables that depend on more than 1 (time) independent variable. This has exception - mechanical models may be referred to as "field theory in 0+1 dimensions", a terminology that may be used to treat these models collectively with true field theories in at least 1+1 dimensions. But when we talk about physics in 3+1 dimensions, things that only depend on "t" as the only independent variable are simply not called fields. That's important because we describe physics in 3+1D as interactions of fields and particles and forces are terms affecting particles not fields

Comment: @LubošMotl That "field" is only used for functions depending on more than one (time) variable isn't standard definition - but nevertheless I can agree. You could just have phrased as "the force isn't a field because the only variable is $t$ and we don't give it the name field"; from here to *"exist objectively..."* is the point I'm missing. $f(t)$ might not be a field in your definition but exists objectively just as much as $f(x,t)$.

Comment: What I demand to objectively exist is a function in Nature that can take almost all values in the space of functions $f(x,y,z)$. The Coulomb formula for the force obviously doesn't satisfy it because it has the universal dependence on a finite number of parameters only. I think that by these constant complaints against the word "objectively", you show you don't get why the word field is used in physics at all. The field is something as real as a planet. It's out there and has some properties. The planet has coordinates $\vec r(t)$, the field has values $\Phi(x,y,z,t)$ at each point.

Comment: What is the difference between two position vectors denoted $\mathbf{a}=x\hat{\textbf{i}}+y\hat{\textbf{j}}+z\hat{\textbf{k}}$ and $\mathbf{b}=x(t)\hat{\textbf{i}}+y(t)\hat{\textbf{j}}+z(t)\hat{\textbf{k}}$? Is the first a function of $(x,y,z)$ and the second a function of just $t$? So $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{a}(x,y,z)$ and $\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{b}(t)$?

Comment: The difference is that you didn't specify any dependence of $\vec a$ but you did specify a dependence of $\vec b$ on $t$. The omission of $(t)$ in the formula for $\vec a$ may be just a shortcut, or an indication that one only talks about one vector. These questions obviously can't be answered by looking at some simple equation only. But in both cases, to say that they are "functions" of $x,y,z$ is immaterial nonsense. $x,y,z$ are just coordinates - which are equivalent to the vector itself. So you're just saying that the vector is a function of itself. Well, yes, it's equal to itself.

Comment: But even if it made sense to say that a vector is a "function" of its own coordinates, it would still not imply that it is automatically a field, as I have argued about 7 times already. Could we please stop this completely unconstructive exchange that leads nowhere?

Answer (score 0):

If an electric force was acting on charge that was spread out continuously over a region, then then each point in that region would have an force vector associated with it, and so in that case there would be a vector function of coordinates describing the forces involved. (There are some issues with each point would have an infinitesimal amount of charge, but I think that can be left for later.)

The the case of a point charge in an electric field, there is really just one point in space of interest, the point where that charge is located.  I guess in a trivial way, you could call the forces a vector field that was zero almost everywhere, except where the charge was located.