# Is the force in Coulomb's law a vector field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vectors, vector-fields, coulombs-law

In the definition of the electric field we have a vector field and a force. The vector field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ is a function of $\mathbf{r}$.

*What about the force, is it a vector $\mathbf{F}$ (not a function of $\mathbf{r}$) or a vector field $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})$?*

The definition is $\mathbf{F}=q\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$, but if we write it explicit, shouldn't it be $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})=q\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$?

I thinking if we have $$
\mathbf{F}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^N q_i\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i\lvert^3}
$$ is it the same as 
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^N q_i\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i\lvert^3} \quad ?
$$
Then $$
\frac{\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})}{q}=
\underbrace{\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{i=1}^N q_i\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i\lvert^3}}_{\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})}=\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})
$$
So $$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})=q\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})
$$
Is this correct or I'm talking rubbish?

Comment: I dont understand your question. It is true that the coulomb force is a vector force field.

Comment: Are you pondering whether the electric field should be a co-vector/one-form field $E=-\mathrm{d}\phi$ rather than a vector field?

Comment: Is there anything that makes you think it wouldn't also be a vector field?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/266930/2451

Comment: The force on a charge at a given position is the value of the electric field at that position, multiplied by the charge of the particle. So indeed, if the electric field varies in space, the force that it would experience also varies in space. The $\mathbf{r}$ dependence is thus implicit in the equation $\mathbf{F} = q \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$, since $\mathbf{F}$ is a vector *field*, as you suspect.